# Increment element in a list and append to new list

Tags: python, list, loops, append, increment

I need to increment a single item in a list (x) and append the result to a new list (y).

This works fine on a single variable as the below example:

```
y = []

for x in range(100):
    x += 1
    print(x)
    y.append(x)

print(y)
```

but when I try to do it within an existing list only the last iteration is being appended to the new list, example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = []
for i in range(100):
    x[1] = x[1] + 1
    print(x)
    y.append(x)

print(y)
```

The desired result is that the 2nd element of list `y[1]` is incremented by `range(100)` in the resulting list `y`, like so:

```
[[1, 3, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 3, 4, 5], [1, 5, 3, 4, 5], ... [1, 101, 3, 4, 5], [1, 102, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You'd need to make a copy of `x` and append that copy to `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same instance of `x` to the list each time, so the resulting values will all be the same.

You could add a copy of `x` instead:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = []
for i in range(100):
    x[1] = x[1] + 1
    print(x)
    y.append(x.copy())

print(y)
```

Obviously there are more efficient ways to do this, but this is a way that is easy to understand.

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 3, 4, 5], ... [1, 100, 3, 4, 5], [1, 101, 3, 4, 5], [1, 102, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: This is great! A lot more helpful than the comment that just said "make a copy of x" lol, first time I've came across ```.copy()``` so thank you.